# Whats wrong with this PHP PDO Update?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I recently switched to PDO to use prepared statements after many wonderful suggestions here. I am trying to convert a simple view counter for use with PDO, but am having trouble getting it to actually update the table. Would you guys mind pointing out what I am doing wrong here? Thanks!

Old Working Code:

```
//Update view counter
$old_views = $postCrumb['topic_views'];
$new_views = $old_views + 1;

$qviewCount = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE cat_id='".$cidClean."' AND id='".$tidClean."' LIMIT 1";
$viewCount = mysql_query($qviewCount) or die(mysql_error());
```

New Non Working Code:

```
//Update view counter
$old_views = $postCrumb['topic_views'];
$new_views = $old_views + 1;

$qviewCount = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE cat_id=? AND id=? LIMIT 1";
$viewCount = $conn->prepare($qViewCount);       
$viewCount -> execute(array($cidClean, $tidClean));
```

I also tried labeling the entries, but this didn't work either:

```
$qviewCount = "UPDATE topics SET topic_views='".$new_views."' WHERE cat_id=':cat_id' AND id=':topic_id' LIMIT 1";
$viewCount = $conn->prepare($qViewCount);   
$viewCount -> execute(array(':topic_id'=>$tidClean,':cat_id'=>$cidClean));
```

Comment: In your last line you have `$viewCount -> execute`, shouldn't the `->` be an `=` and then put `$conn->execute(...)`

Comment: @ph34r: what if you `var_dump($viewCount->errorInfo());` after your code?

Comment: btw, use `SET topic_views = topic_views + 1` instead of manual incrementing

Comment: Thanks zerkms, I didn't know you could do it that way instead of manually. The error I'ts throwing is:

 `array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "42000" [1]=> int(1065) [2]=> string(15) "Query was empty" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you are declaring `$qviewCount` (small 'V') and the one you are passing to `PDO::Prepare` `$qViewCount` (capital 'V') are not the same. Therefore the error is correct in telling you they query is empty (since you never initialized `$qViewCount` (with a capital 'V') to a value.

Comment: Doh! I've been staring at this so long trying to figure out what I did wrong, I have no idea how I missed that! Thanks a bunch.